# What is the type of function in flow javascript type checker?

Tags: javascript, function, flowtype

How would you define type for functions in flow, in the context of function getting passed in as argument? For eg, afterDoneSomething below is callback function that's getting passed - I'm not sure how I define it's type with flow.

```
function doSomething(path:string, afterDoneSomething:<What is the Type>)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the doc: http://flowtype.org/docs/functions.html, you need to supply the type of the function's parameters and returned value: `(P1: T1, .., Pn: Tn) => U`

So suppose your `afterDoneSomething` takes a number and return a number, it should be annotated as

```
function doSomething(path:string, afterDoneSomething: (x: number) => number)
```

Comment: And what if the function doesn't return anything?

Comment: @NikSo () => void